# RxJS - Finalize not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

For a logout request, I want to dispatch the same actions when the request is successful as well as when it fails. For this, I thought about using the `finalize()` operator.

However, it seems I can't get it working, as it appears to never get executed.

The effect:

```
/**
 * When the user logs out :
 * Try to delete its push token
 * Clear user
 */
logout$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ClassicAuthActions.logout),
        switchMap(action => this.api.logout().pipe(
            map(() => ClassicAuthActions.logoutDidSuccess()),
            catchError(err => of(ClassicAuthActions.logoutDidFail())),
            finalize(() => of(
                    ClassicAuthActions.deleteUserCommunicationToken(),
                    ClassicAuthActions.clearUser(action.redirect)
            )),
        ))
    )
);
```

I'm rather new to RxJS so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `finalize` is a side effect operator, you cannot return an observable from it. You're probably looking for something like `endsWith`.

Comment: Ingo is right. I'd like to add that if your source observable comes from a `fromEvent` or an Http call from the angular HttpClient, those observables are set to never complete and that's why you'll never get the `finalize()` callback

Comment: HttpClient requests do complete, for fromEvent you're right.

Comment: `endWith()` did the trick! Thank you for help. Feel free to share the solution so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Great! I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finalize` is a side effect operator, so you cannot really return further values from it.

If you just want to end an observable with some value, you can use `endWith`:

```
numbers$.pipe(endWith(42));
```

For more complex scenarios like ending with another observable, something like `concatWith` would be the way to go:

```
numbers$.pipe(concatWith(of(42)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you `switchMap` to what appears to be an HTTP call, nothing will happen until `logout$` has a subscriber

In the case of an error you don't appear to be rethrowing the error in the `catchError`. Since you caught `finalize` there is no error anymore which is why it is not called on error.

Comment: `finalize` is piped to the logout call, so whether or not `actions$` completes doesn't matter, but rather whether `logout()` completes.

Comment: Completely missed the switchMap wth